# Should I always rebuild indexes after Bulk Insert or just periodically?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert, indexing

I understand that Bulk Insert ignores indexes.  If I have a 100 million record table and I'm inserting 30-50k records a day using Bulk Insert, would there be a big difference between rebuilding the indexes weekly versus daily?

Comment: You might want to at least update your statistics daily (nightly) to make sure the query optimizer has an accurate idea of the data distribution in your tables, for optimal query plan selection.

Comment: @marc_s Sounds like a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bulk insert updates indexes just as a normal insert in SQLServer. It does NOT ignore them.

Rebuilding indexes is like defragging a disk. With 50k inserts a weekly rebuild is generous. Monthly ould be fine.

Comment: Ok now I'm wondering where I ever got that idea.  I think I must have just seen that it can ignore constraints and jumped to that conclusion for some odd reason.